# What is the difference between ng-if and *ng-if in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to understand the difference between `ng-if` and `*ng-if`, but they look the same to me.

Is there a difference that I should keep in mind choosing one over the other and when to use these directives?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`ngIf` is the directive. Because it's a structural directive (template-based), you need to use the `*` prefix to use it into templates.

`*ngIf` corresponds to the shortcut for the following syntax ("syntactic sugar"):

```
<template [ngIf]="condition">
  <p>
    Our heroes are true!
  </p>
</template>
```

Equivalent to:

```
<p *ngIf="condition">
  Our heroes are true!
</p>
```

See this doc for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Answer (score 16):

The difference is that both are not supported in Angular2 ;-) at least in current versions - it should be `*ngIf` or `ngIf`.

Structural directives can be used with explicit `<template>` tags or implicit `<template>` tag. For the implicit version a `*` is required to indicate it is a structural directive.

**explicit**

```
<template [ngIf]="someExpr">
   <div>content</div>
</template>
```

or since 2.0.0 preferred

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someExpr">
   <div>content</div>
</ng-container>
```

**implicit**

```
<div *ngIf="someExpr"></div>
```

Usually you will use the implicit version because it is more concise.

**When to use the explicit version?**

There are use cases where the implicit version doesn't work.

- If you want to apply more than one structural directive like `ngFor` **and** `ngIf` which is not supported, then you can use the explicit form for one of these.

Instead of this invalid syntax

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" *ngIf="!item.hidden"></div>
```

you can use

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngIf="!itemHidden></div>
</ng-container>
```

- If you want to apply the structural directive to more than one element

For example you want to list several items with `name` and `price` per row

```
<tr>
  <td *ngFor="???">item.name</td>
  <td>item.price</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>item.name</td>
    <td>item.price</td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

To keep it simple, in the latest angular versions to date, for example when we use *ngIf like below.

```
<div *ngIf = "condition">
//code here
</div>
```

Now, the above code is actually rendered by angular as below:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition">
<div>
//code here
</div>
</ng-template>
```

Hence we can either use *ngIf directly as a structural directive or we can use [ngIf] as attribute directive but with a ng-template. Hope this makes things more clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Currently in Angular we use ngIf instead of ng-if so considering the difference here we can implement it rather this way:
In case of *ngIf - `<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>`

In case of ngIf - `<ng-template [ngIf]="condition"><div>Content to render when condition is true.</div></ng-template>`

You can find this detailed on angular.io>API references